# HTML label for Yii Bootsrap widget TbButton

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, label

I have used a Yii Bootstrap widget in my web page. This is my code:

```
<?php
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'buttonType'=>'submit',
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>'S U B M I <br>T',
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'name'=>'step2',
            'id'=>'winery-selected',
            'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-responsive'
         )
    )); 
?>

<br/>
```

I want to add a `br` tag inside the `label` element. If I just add a `br` tag inside the `label`, it is displayed as shown in the image below.

[image]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line , `'encodeLabel'=>false,`

Here is your code should be ,

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                            'buttonType'=>'submit',
                            'encodeLabel'=>false,
                            'type'=>'primary',
                            'label'=>'S U B M I <br>T',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'step2','id'=>'winery-selected','class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-responsive')
                        )); ?>
```